# Defensive Duelist with Great Weapon Fighter when equipping Sunblade

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, feat-qualifications

Since sunblade is both *versatile* and *finesse*, is it possible to take advantage of both *Defensive Duelist* and *Great Weapon Fighter* when two handing it.

I've been told you cannot use *Defensive Duelist* while dual-wielding or with a shield, but what about *two-handed* or *versatile*?

Are you still only wielding one weapon for the purposes of *Defensive Duelist*?

Comment: Hi Tory, I removed the bold in that first revision because when half a whole message is bolded, the bold formatting loses its point and its effect. Since it was unnecessary for such a short message here anyway, I removed it.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.**

Defensive Duelist applies whenever you are wielding a finesse weapon. Nothing about Defensive Duelist or the finesse property requires you to wield that weapon in one hand.

Answer (score 0):

Defensive duelist does apply in your described situation, but also when dual wielding or with a shield. Nothing in the feat description says that it requires a free hand. 5th edition works on a philosophy that if it wouldnt work in a certain way, it would say so.